# Div inside rotated div

Tags: jquery, html, background-image, mask

Is it possible to use a div, rotated 45 degrees, as mask(alpha) for image or div containing img?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2G9f.jpg

Comment: Do you want the image rotated as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just rotate the inner element by -45 degrees?

```
div.mask {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg); 
}

div.mask img {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg); 
}
```

Example JSFiddle provided by **subhaze** - **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/xLgyN/1)**

Comment: Was just about to edit with a working example. But I guess it's a joint effort ;)

Comment: haha def, I jumped on jsfiddle to mock it up and got back you had posted... Figured it would be a waist to not add it in the comments :P

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Jquery plugin this would do what you need [jqueryrotate](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/)
this is very easy to use and you dont need to imply any css and it is cross browser too.

Answer (score 0):

You may CSS `transform` property.

Refer this: http://davidwalsh.name/css-transform-rotate